# Search with spaces in CodeIgniter Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a function that I'll use to search users. But .... I need to search it with spaces between names.

For example, seaching 'John Doe':

My URL should be:

> https://localhost/cp/admin/users/get/John Doe

I don't have any idea how to do that and however, I getting null response because he can't identify the spaces.

Code (I don't know how this might help, but ok.):

```
public function get($username) {
    $res = $this->db->where("username", $username)->get("users");
    $res = array("user" => $res->row());
    echo json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to start helping us help you by adding some code

Comment: Right. What do you think should be added? I just need to search users with space between names, e.g: John Doe. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass url parameters like that.

You need to `urlencode()` before appending to the url and `urldecode()` in your controller.

`urlencode()` replaces all non-safe characters with safe ones. `urldecode` does the exact opposite.

For your example, `John Doe` becomes `John+Doe` in the url and `John Doe` in your controller, after you decode it.